Dynamic response for dynamic request in SOAP UI using GROOVY
It is probably necessary to generate xml responses depending on the request
For example, there is such xml for a request:
REQUEST
<wrap:someWrapper>
   <item1>1</item1>
   <item2>1</item1>
   <item7>1</item1>
</wrap:someWrapper>

RESPONSE LIST

For item1 response will look like this:

<wrap:someWrapper>
   <field1>value</field1>
   <field2>value</field2>
</wrap:someWrapper>


For item2 response will look like this:

<wrap:someWrapper>
   <field2>value</field2>
   <field3>value</field3>
   <field4>value</field4>
</wrap:someWrapper>

Depending on what tags were received in the request, a dynamic response should be generated.
RESPONSE for example, if we sent only 2 items:
<wrap:someWrapperBase>
   <wrap:someWrapperForFirstItem>
      <field1>value</field1>
      <field2>value</field2>
   </wrap:someWrapperForFirstItem>
   <wrap:someWrapperForSecondItem>
      <field2>value</field2>
      <field3>value</field3>
      <field4>value</field4>
   </wrap:someWrapperForSecondItem>
</wrap:someWrapperBase>

Maybe we need to write some kind of groovy foreach:: here is the pseudocode i am presenting
for (item in listItemInRequestWrapper) {
   if (item1.value == 1) {
      dynamicXmlResponse.addResponseBodyForItem1Request();
   }
   if (item2.value == 1) {
      dynamicXmlResponse.addResponseBodyForItem2Request();
   }
   if (item3.value == 1) {
      dynamicXmlResponse.addResponseBodyForItem3Request();
   }

   ...

   if (itemN.value == 1) {
      dynamicXmlResponse.addResponseBodyForItemNRequest();
   }
}

And the Response that will be displayed looks like this
<response>
   ${dynamicXmlResponse}
</response>

I will accept any ideas, since I myself am very inexperienced in neither groovy nor in mocks
